# ASP.Net MVC Model Binding IEnumerable Failing

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an application that should display a list of objects from a local database in some textfields with the option to edit them. The code correctly returns an object from the list when it is edited, but my controller doesn't see any of the changes. I have tried switching from an `IEnumerable` to a `IList` to no avail. Any ideas as to why this is failing(code below)?

Model:

```
public class EmployeeProject
{
    [Required()]
    public Int32 EmployeeProjectID { get; set; }
    [Required()]
    [Range(0, 999999999, ErrorMessage = "Not a valid ID")]
    public Int32 EmployeeID { get; set; }
    [Required()]
    public Int32 ProjectID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Project")]
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }
    [Range(0.0, 1.0, ErrorMessage = "Must be between 0 and 1")]
    public double Hour1 { get; set; }
    ....

    public EmployeeProject()
    {
        EmployeeID = 0;
        ProjectID = 0;
        Hour1 = 0;
        ....
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "EmployeeProjectID,EmployeeID,ProjectID,EmployeeName,ProjectName,Hour1,Hour2,Hour3,Hour4")] EmployeeProject employeeProject)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Entry(employeeProject).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(employeeProject);
}
```

View:

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication1.Models.EmployeeProject>
....
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EmployeeName)</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ProjectName)</th>
        ....        
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        using (Html.BeginForm("Edit","EmployeeProject",item))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            <tr>
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => item.EmployeeProjectID)
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => item.EmployeeID)
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => item.ProjectID)
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.EmployeeName)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => item.EmployeeName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.ProjectName)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => item.ProjectName)
                </td>
                ....
                <td class="form-group">
                    <td class="col-md-offset-0 col-md-5">
                        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
                    </td>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    }
</table>
```

Comment: You model is a collection and you cannot use a `foreach` loop to generate form controls for a collection (your generating `name` attributes which have no relationship to your model so wont bind to anything). But then you creating one form for each item in the collection and you can only post back one form at a time so that makes no sense. Then your code would start throwing exceptions because in the POST method you return a single `EmployeeProject` to a view expecting `IEnumerable<EmployeeProject>`.

Comment: Show your GET method. Are you trying to edit one `EmployeeProject` or a collection of `EmployeeProject`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how i did in one of my project

```
@model List<Game>
@using (Html.BeginForm(FormMethod.Post))
{
 @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
 @for (int i = 0; i < Model.OrderGames.Count(); i++)
 {
 <tr>  
    <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.OrderGames[i].GameId})</td>     
    <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.OrderGames[i].NumberOfPlayers})</td>
    <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.OrderGames[i].GameTime})</td>
    <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.OrderGames[i].Price})</td>                                           
</tr>                                    
}
}
```

Here you can translate to your project.
Your controller should be like this

```
[Httppost]
public ActionResult Edit(List<Game> Games){}
```

Answer (score 1):

Strange is that in your action method you are returning a single instance saying 
`return View(employeeProject);`  whereas in your view you are expecting a `IEnumerable<employeeProject>` cause you have

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication1.Models.EmployeeProject>
```

How do you think that's going to work anyways. Your model should just be

```
@model WebApplication1.Models.EmployeeProject
```

(OR) If you really want then change your action method to take a list of `employeeProject`

```
public ActionResult Edit(List<EmployeeProject> employeeProjects)
{
```

Comment: I should have included this initially, but from my Edit in my Controller, it returns to View which returns the list. I have updated the question

Comment: @Daniel, that's totally wrong. You should consider separating them in different page or create a partial view for that purpose.

Comment: That's not particularly helpful, I don't understand what is wrong with my solution(though obviously something's not right, can't argue with you there). Could you please be more specific about what is wrong and what the purpose of the separate page/partial view would be?